# Additional differences of Rashi's Torah scroll

Tags: rashi, sefer-torah

Rashi on [Shmot 25,20](https://www.sefaria.org.il/Rashi_on_Exodus.25.22.3?vhe=Rashi_Chumash,_Metsudah_Publications,_2009&lang=he&with=Siftei%20Chakhamim&lang2=he) interprets the Vav we don't have in our Torah scrolls:

> "*ואת כל אשר אצוה אותך אל בני ישראל*. **הרי וי"ו זו יתירה** וטפלה, וכמוהו הרבה במקרא"

Siftey Chachamim explains:

> "אע"פ שאין כתיב ואת בוי"ו בס"ת של רש"י היה כתיב בוי"ו ע"פ המסורת:"

What additional Masoret does S"C mean and what additional mentions of differences between Rashi's Torah scroll and ours are there?